# Count down timer in coming soon page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a count down timer in Vanilla Javascript. Below is the code:-

```
var futureDate = new Date("oct 31,2021 10:00:00").getTime();
var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
var diffTime = futureDate - currentDate;
console.log(diffTime);
var days = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000* 24* 60*60));
console.log(days);
var hours = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60));
console.log(hours);
var minutes = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60));
console.log(minutes);
var seconds = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000));
console.log(seconds);
```

Below is the output of the code provided in the console.

[image]

This output is in accordance with below image

[image]

But I am failing to understand the particular code written in w3schools as highlighted in blue color in the image below
[image]

I am not able to figure out the difference between 2 code written?

Answer (score 0):

[`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1900-01-01 00:00:00).

When you subtract the time between 2 dates, you will get the time difference in milliseconds. In your code, you are showing

1. The total number of hours between the dates
2. The total number of minutes between the dates
3. The total number of seconds between the dates

Let's take the number of hours as an example, the code written in w3schools takes the remainder from dividing the time difference by the number of milliseconds per day. This way, you will get the time difference in less than 24 hours and you can use it to calculate the time difference in hours.

Do the same for the minutes and seconds and you will get the same result written in w3schools

```js
var futureDate             = new Date( "oct 31,2021 10:00:00" ).getTime();
var currentDate            = new Date().getTime();
var timeDiffInMilliseconds = futureDate - currentDate;
var millisecondsPerSecond  = 1000;
var millisecondsPerMinute  = millisecondsPerSecond * 60; // 1000 * 60
var millisecondsPerHour    = millisecondsPerMinute * 60; // 1000 * 60 * 60
var millisecondsPerDay     = millisecondsPerHour   * 24; // 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

console.log( 'timeDiffInMilliseconds: ' + timeDiffInMilliseconds );

var days = Math.floor( timeDiffInMilliseconds / millisecondsPerDay );
console.log( 'days: ' + days );

var timeDiffInLessThan1Day = timeDiffInMilliseconds % millisecondsPerDay;
var hours                  = Math.floor( timeDiffInLessThan1Day / millisecondsPerHour );
console.log( 'hours: ' + hours );

var timeDiffInLessThan1Hour = timeDiffInMilliseconds % millisecondsPerHour;
var minutes                 = Math.floor( timeDiffInLessThan1Hour / millisecondsPerMinute );
console.log( 'minutes: ' + minutes );

var timeDiffInLessThan1Minute = timeDiffInMilliseconds % millisecondsPerMinute;
var seconds                   = Math.floor( timeDiffInLessThan1Minute / millisecondsPerSecond );
console.log( 'seconds: ' + seconds );
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first you need to understand the basic concept of dates in `vanilla` `javascript`.

> 1 second = 1000 milliseconds 
> 1 minute = 60 seconds 
> 1 hour = 60 minutes 
> 1 day = 24 hours 
> [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) is simply used for returning the highest rounded value possible.

Now coming to your question,

```
var distance = countDownDate - now;
```

This line basically takes two UNIX format date integers and gives you the difference in the form of [unix timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). So once you get the difference you need to find out how many `hours`, `minutes` and `days` it comprises of, and that's just it.

We use the simple formulas I mentioned to top to identify just that.
`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` is 1 day
So we divide the total difference in two dates by `the 1 day` to get the number of days in total with the following line:

```
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Similarly, with the code below, we take the difference in two dates and first get the number of days from it and then whatever time remains we use that time to further calculate the hours by dividing the value by `(1000 * 60 * 60)`.

```
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
```

The following line first calculates the number of hours from the difference and then whatever remains is then further divided by a minute to get the totals minutes remaining. Similarly, concept will be applied to calculate the seconds.

```
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
```